# Install Mosquitto service on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to install Mosquitto service on Amazon Linux AWS machine? How to do that?

Command below reports `No package mosquitto available.`

```
sudo yum -y install mosquitto
```

Answer (score -2):

Mosquito had official website. Please read the guide for more information.

The binary packages listed below are supported by the Mosquitto project. In many cases Mosquitto is also available directly from official Linux/BSD distributions

If still not success, you can download source code then build by your self.

http://mosquitto.org/download/